# Posting Variables from jQueryUI Dialog to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to get the Inputs from Input Text-Fields in an Dialog window to use them for a SQL query.

My Problem is that i cant use the array in PHP. Im getting no error or sucess message.
In the Network log of Firefox i can see the Post method with the right Values.

Heres a snippet of my js code:

```
<script>
    // open popup window "dialog"
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false ,
                width: 1000,
                buttons: {
                    "Quelle hinzufügen": function() {                           

                        var out = [document.getElementById("titelin"),document.getElementById("autorin"),document.getElementById("tagsin"),document.getElementById("linkin")];
                        var outv = [out[0].value,out[1].value,out[2].value,out[3].value];                       
                        ajax(outv);
                    },
                Abbrechen: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }   
                }   
            }); 
            $( "#opener" ).click(function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
            });
        });
        // posting to PHP
        function ajax(outv){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"quellenverzeichnis.php",
                data: {output: outv},               
                sucess: function(){
                    alert("works");
                },
                error:  function(){
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        }; 
    </script>
```

Heres my PHP code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['output'])){
    hinzufuegen();
};
printf($_POST['output']);

?>
```

Don´t know what I am doing wrong and sorry for my bad english and the German words in the code.
Thanks for your help

Comment: `data: {output: bla},` where is this bla coming from?

Comment: that why your request is going blank as undefined `bla` would not send `output` field

Comment: printf($_Post['output']); is wrong you should use printf($_POST['output']);

Comment: sorry that bla thing was just a test with a string instead of an array

Comment: Please put actual code so we wont have to dig in different direction

Comment: data: {output: bla} probably need to be data: {output: outv}

Comment: sorry im a bit tired , but it should be actual code now....still dont work

Comment: check my answer below and let us know If you are getting any error in console or at PHP side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code snippets

```
         buttons: {
              "Quelle hinzufügen": function() {
                 var out = [];
                 out.push(document.getElementById("titelin").value);
                 out.push(document.getElementById("autorin").value);
                 out.push(document.getElementById("tagsin").value);
                 out.push(document.getElementById("linkin").value);
                 ajax(out);
         },
```

And

```
        function ajax(info){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"quellenverzeichnis.php",
                data: {output: info},                
                success: function(data){
                    alert("works"+data);
                },
                error:  function(){
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
        };
```

And

```
        $_POST['output']
```

Comment: thanks for your help it works...but my problem was that i expected an print on the site but its ok like that

Comment: did you try echo? I have updated the code again, try this now

Comment: sucess message dont pop up, but i got the array in php and can do the sql request

Comment: there was typo in your code for `sucess` callback it should be `success`, please try my new updated code